# why Explain shows 'using where' instead of 'using index' on indexed column?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql and my table type is myisam with 100 million records.

This table have 90 columns and indexes added on 30 columns.

I run this query "select id from tablename where id between num1 and num2". This results in almost 10 seconds.
Now I add in where condition date like, "select id from tablename where id between num1 and num2 and date between date1 and date2". And it results in 4 minutes.

'date' field is also indexed.

In first case in Explain, it shows "using index" in "extra" column, while in second case in Explain, it shows "using where" in "extra" column.

I don't understand the reason for different behaviour of Explain, and difference in time taken for query.
Please anyone explain me these, so that I can work in right direction for optimizing query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an index that includes both columns, `id` and `date` in that order? If not, create one. Indexes are used most efficiently when they closely match the `where` condition (or otherwise: match your `where` conditions to your indexes).

If you have an index on the `id` column and the `where` clause only uses that column, the index can be used efficiently.

If you have two columns in the `where` condition and no matching index is found, a full table scan is performed.

Comment: For a condition like `expr1 AND expr2 AND ...` a matching index for any of the expressions can be used. It is better if a composite index matches multiple expressions, but in this case it is not possible because both conditions are ranges. An index on `(id,date)` may help by allowing mysql to filter from the index instead of the table (as a covering index), but it will not be a direct lookup.

Comment: Does this mean that two fields in where condition and both individually indexed,but mysql will use only one index? I have total 10 fields in where clause in my actual query, so Do I need to make index with all these fields combined? I have these two fields are ranges and other 8 fields are large number set, like 'fieldname in (1,2,3,..)'.

Comment: An index with multiple columns will probably be better. You can have only one range condition in the index lookup and it will be the last used column in the index, so you should put the ones with the `=` conditions first. Also you should avoid putting columns with low cardinality (low uniqueness) in the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

`select id from tablename where id between num1 and num2`

This can be resolved from the `id` index only, without touching the table at all. That is what `using index` means.

`select id from tablename where id between num1 and num2 and date between date1 and date2`

MySQL will get the internal ROWIDs from the `id` index, then go to the actual table and fetch all the corresponding rows, so it can check if the date is `between date1 and date2`.